# Adding more data points to the list by averaging parent data points

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list `"{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3},{x4,y4},{x5,y5},....,{xn,yn}}"` and now want to modify it as below

```
"{{x1,y1},{(3x1+x2)/4,(3y1+y2)/4},{(x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2},{(x1+3x2)/4,(y1+3y2)/4},{x2,y2},.....,{xn,yn}".
```

For example: {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}. I want this list to be modified as {{1,2},{1.5,2.5},{2,3},{2.5,3.5},{3,4},{3.5,4.5},{4,5},{4.5,5.5},{5,6}}.

Adding two more data points in between parent data points by averaging them. It helps to get more data points on the list.
Please help.

Comment: You are adding **three** data points between parent points rather than two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`TimeSeriesResample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesResample.html):

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
withIndices = Transpose[{Range[Length[data]], data}];
TimeSeriesResample[withIndices, 1/4, 
  ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1}][[All, 2]]

(* {{1, 2}, {3/2, 5/2}, {2, 3}, {5/2, 7/2}, {3, 4}, {7/2, 9/2},
    {4, 5}, {9/2, 11/2}, {5, 6}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html):

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
J = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Table[{x, J[x]}, {x, 1, 5, 1/2}] // N
(*    {{1., 2.}, {1.5, 2.5}, {2., 3.}, {2.5, 3.5}, {3., 4.},
       {3.5, 4.5}, {4., 5.}, {4.5, 5.5}, {5., 6.}}              *)
```

By changing the [`InterpolationOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html) option you can play with the way the interpolation is done.

Comment: @flinty, Bob Hanlon and, Roman, Thanks very much. All works great.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
```

Using [`Subdivide`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html)

```
DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[Subdivide[##, 4] & @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1], 1]

(* {{1, 2}, {3/2, 5/2}, {2, 3}, {5/2, 7/2}, {3, 4}, {7/2, 9/2}, {4, 5}, 
  {9/2, 11/2}, {5, 6}} *)

% /. r_Rational :> N[r]

(* {{1, 2}, {1.5, 2.5}, {2, 3}, {2.5, 3.5}, {3, 4}, {3.5, 4.5}, {4, 5}, 
  {4.5, 5.5}, {5, 6}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation on BobHanlon's idea: using [`Subdivide`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html) with [`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html):

```
ClearAll[f]

f = Prepend[First @ #] @ BlockMap[Apply[##2 & @@ Subdivide[##, 4] &], #, 2, 1] &

f @ data
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3/2, 5/2}, {2, 3}, {5/2, 7/2}, {3, 4}, {7/2, 9/2}, 
>  {4, 5}, {9/2, 11/2}, {5, 6}}
> ```

Alternatively, `Subdivide` + [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html):

```
ClearAll[f2]

f2 = Prepend[First@ #] @ MapThread[##2 & @@ Subdivide[##, 4] &, {Most @ #, Rest @ #}] &

f2 @ data
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3/2, 5/2}, {2, 3}, {5/2, 7/2}, {3, 4}, {7/2, 9/2}, 
>  {4, 5}, {9/2, 11/2}, {5, 6}}
> ```